# Dynamic Not Dragging in jQuery UI, but Static Image Does

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a static image that I am able to move around via the jQuery UI 'draggable' function.  However, if I try to put the same kind of image in the same spot, dynamically, the image isn't able to be dragged, can someone tell me what I have to do in order to make dynamic images draggable?

The following will work:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#marker').draggable();
    }

    <div id="imgId">
        <div id="markersDiv">
            <img src="include/images/sign_here.jpg" id="marker" draggable="true" style="position: absolute; left: 635px; top: 458px;" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

But if I create the image dynamically using JavaScript, and append it into that div, it will not work.

```
    var dynImage = document.createElement("img");
    dynImage.setAttribute('src', 'include/images/sign_here.jpg');
    dynImage.setAttribute('id', 'marker');
    dynImage.setAttribute('draggable', 'true');
    dynImage.style.left = "635px";
    dynImage.style.top = "458px";
    dynImage.style.position = "absolute";

    document.getElementById("markersDiv").appendChild(dynImage);
```

And the HTML is the same:

```
     <div id="imgId">
        <div id="markersDiv">
        </div>
    </div>
```

This adds the image, but it is not draggable.  Is there a reason why or am I doing something wrong.  If so, does anyone have any suggestions on how to make it work?  Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I figured out my problem.  I have to add the 'draggable' function into the JavaScript dynamic creation of the image, after the image.  I have it working now, thanks regardless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding:

```
    $('#marker').draggable();
```

After it is appended to the div, in the JavaScript, on the next line, I was able to get the image to drag, sorry to waste everyone's time on this!!